# How to set up performance test for Microsoft Sync Framework?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

We developed a Client Server application using Microsoft Sync Framework to synchronize data between a WinForm client application (with a SQL CE Local Cache database) and a SQL SErver 2008 database server.  The application is now pretty much completed, and all features seem working properly.  So now we want to use Visual Studio 2008 Test edition to create performance test (on the server, like simulating 10 user simultaneous syncing with the server database for 20 minutes), load test on bandwidth (how much network traffic will be generated), and so on.  Basically we want to simulate the real life situation and see of the our system (with Sync Framework) and handle it.

However, because of the nature of sync, we can't just use VS Test edition to create load test and keep banging the server, because in order to actually simulate each client properly, each client has to have it's own SQLCE Local Cache database.  Does it mean that I need to set up 10 client in 10 different folder, and then use VS Test edition to kick them off?  Or is there any better way to set up the test?

And does anyone have any experience on setting up load and performance testing for Sync Framework?  Thanks!